# How can we control TPS using tornado asynchronous networking library?

Tags: python, http

Please find below code which generates HTTP calls from provided file. But how to control per second calls?

```
from datetime import datetime
from tornado import ioloop, httpclient
i = 0
def handle_request(response):
    print(datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),url,response.code)
    global i
    i -= 1
    if i == 0:
        ioloop.IOLoop.instance().stop()
http_client = httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
for url in open('urls.txt'):
    i += 1
    http_client.fetch(url.strip(), handle_request, method='GET')
ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```